# Системы счисления

Tags: информатика

Сколько разрядов потребуется для того чтобы перевести 128 бит в 16 ричную систему счисления?

Answer (score 1):

Речь идет, я так понимаю, о шестнадцатеричных разрядах? Если да, то: 16, как известно, это 2 в четвертой степени. Следовательно, одну шестнадцатеричную цифру можно закодировать четырьмя двоичными  цифрами (битами). Следовательно, для представления числа, которое в двоичной форме занимает 128 бит, шестнадцатеричных цифр нужно в 4 раза меньше. Правильный ответ...думаю, догадаетесь)